# How do I check that a mysql query was successful with || in a shell script?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I'm unsure where to place my success message function which works like so:

```
    responseMessage() {
    echo "$1" || echo "$2"
}
```

I'd call it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

password='123456'

responseMessage() {
    echo "$1"|| echo "$2"
}

mysql <<MYSQL 
UPDATE users SET password='${password}' where ID='1';

MYSQL && responseMessage "Successfully updated password." "Failed to update password"
```

I'm unsure where I should be putting the function.

Placing it where it is in the example above, I get the following:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ bash testmysql.sh
testmysql.sh: line 12: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `MYSQL')
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

I would expect the No Database selected error since it is correct, however I'd expect the second argument of responseMessage to be printed.

Is this something obvious?
Thanks

Edit:
Also tried the following:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ bash testmysql.sh
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 2: No database selected
user@DESKTOP:~$ cat testmysql.sh
#!/bin/bash

responseMessage() {
    echo "$1" || echo "$2"
}

mysql <<MYSQL && responseMessage "Successfully updated password." "Failed to update password"

UPDATE users SET password='123456' where ID='1';

MYSQL
```

I deffo would have thought this would work, as per https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1121

--

I also created the function based on this which does what I'd expect:

```
user@DESKTOP:~$ bash testmysql.sh
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 2: No database selected
Failed to recreate the schemata.
user@DESKTOP:~$ cat testmysql.sh
#!/bin/bash

responseMessage() {
    echo "$1" || echo "$2"
}

mysql <<MYSQL && echo "Successfully recreated the schemata." || echo "Failed to recreate the schemata."

UPDATE users SET password='123456' where ID='1';

MYSQL
```

Comment: Why do you think that `echo` would fail?

Comment: Well the echo function works by itself. So it's clearly the position, right?
And the && operator only runs if the previous exited without a failure code. 
I don't really understand why the "&& function" can't be after the second MYSQL though.
Edit: I did just find this though: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1121

Comment: I also found I missed a space between:
`echo "$1"|| echo "$2"` and should be `echo "$1" || echo "$2"`

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql <<MYSQL && responseMessage "Successfully updated password." "Failed to update password"
```

Your function `responseMessage` will print "Successfully recreated the schemata." when `mysql` succeeds, as you want, but won't run at all if it fails because you placed it behind `&&`. In other words, your code reads "_If and only if `mysql` succeeds, run my function, else do nothing" and your function reads "print out the first argument, or if printing the first argument fails, print the second argument."

The function you want looks something more like this:

```
responseMessage() {
  returnCode="$1"
  successMessage="$2"
  failureMessage="$3"
  if [[ $returnCode == "0" ]]; then
    echo "$successMessage"
  else
    echo "$failureMessage"
  fi
}
```

And your command would become:

```
mysql <<MYSQL; responseMessage $? "Successfully updated password." "Failed to update password"
```

You can use a line break instead of the semicolon if you prefer. Of course, this only works as long as the function is called immediately after the command you want to check, or else `$?` will have the exit code for another command.

Comment: Thanks this was a new way of error catching for me ($?).

`user@DESKTOP:~$ bash testmysql.sh`
`ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 2: No database selected`

^ So I expect the mysql error, but I was expeting the "Failed to update password" to echo. However, based on the position of the function, it feels like responseMessage is checking to see whether MySQL opened ok.. but even then, still no echo. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I pointed out that the function shouldn't be behind `&&` and then made the same mistake myself. I'm updating my answer to put it behind a semicolon instead (but a line break would be fine as well).

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for the use of heredocs and checking the exit code value. This still doesn't really solve that I wanted to turn my responses into a function, but it's better than what I was doing before.

```
result=$(mysql <<MYSQL

UPDATE users SET password='123456' where ID='1';

MYSQL

)

[ $? = 0 ] && echo "Success" || echo "Failed"
```